# Sync Sqlite data with MySql database using android application

Tags: android

I have developed an Hangman Web and Mobile Application,Iam storing the score of the player in a table in mysql database in web application for mobile application Iam storing the score in the local sqlite database. Now my requirement is to sync these both scores.Is it possible and should i use web services for that? 
Please help in solving this

Comment: you need to use web services for fetching the data from the server and then sync with local DB for avoiding use of internet data frequently.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example

Comment: don't have the example.. simple scenario, fetch data from the server and sync with the local DB, then populate it to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for retrieve data from Mysql database

```
public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB() {
        // Create AsycHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        // Http Request Params Object
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        client.post("Your Url", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.d("Rs service_ReloadSqlDB ", response);
                updateSQLite(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(throwable);
                Log.d(" RS onFailure ", throwable.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Use this to insert in SQLite that retrieve data

```
 public void updateSQLite(String response) {
        try {
            // Extract JSON array from the response
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println(arr.length());
            // If no of array elements is not zero
            if (arr.length() != 0) {
                // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has userid and username
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    // Get JSON object
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                    String st = obj.get("Games_Name").toString();
                    String ste = obj.get("Games_PackageName").toString();

                    // Insert User into SQLite DB
                    //   databaseHelper.insertUser(queryValues);
                    databaseHelper.insertGameInfo(st, ste);
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), " service_ReloadSqlDB...UPDated....  Work .....");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```